# How to create multiple editor for custom post types post?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

I want to create multiple editors for my custom post type `packages` posts. That is for a 3 day package I want to add descriptions for each day like day 1, day 2 and day 3. For 5 day package there should be 5 editors like that.

Answer (score 2):

Hello you have to create multiple metaboxes as your editor. try below code and place this code in your functions.php file it will create another text area with wp_editor in your custom-post-type and remember one thing just change custom-post-type with the name of your custom-post-type in below code.

```
add_action("admin_init", "subdescription");
add_action('save_post', 'save_subdescription');
function subdescription(){
add_meta_box("sub_description", "Sub Description", "meta_function", "custom-post-type");
}
function meta_function(){
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$sub_description = $custom["sub_description"][0];
wp_editor( $sub_description, 'subdescription', $settings =
array('textarea_name'=>'sub_description','dfw'=>true) );
}
function save_subdescription(){
global $post;
update_post_meta($post->ID, "sub_description", $_POST["sub_description"]);
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: yeah its fine, but i need add another editors like this for each packages according to the duration of packages. I mean there  i need to add editors by clicking a plus button to create new one instantly.

Comment: For that you have to code a little more or you can use ACF repeater plugin  it will repeat another row every time whenever you click on add row button. for more detail. visit below link
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/